# Why do my program stops when inserting values to a MAP?

Tags: c++, file, dictionary, coding-style, fstream

I try to read a file into a map but the program stops in the middle of the file.
The file consists millionss of lines, each line is a STRING composed of numbers and an INT.
 e.g. 1230981237120313 123.

```
#include<map>
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
void main ()
{
    ifstream mapfile("filename.txt",ifstream::in);
    int itemp;
    string stemp;
    map<string,int> mapping;
    while(mapfile>>stemp>>itemp)
    {
        mapping[stemp]=itemp;

    }
}
```

When it deals with small files with hundreds of lines, it is ok. But when it reaches more then 90 million lines, it stops without reporting any error and just stops with a "Press any key to continue...".

I've done some analysis and I can make sure the program stops after reading the line in the file and when it needs to do  `mapping[stemp]=itemp` . And every time it stops, it happens at different lines but always around 90 million.

Could anyone tell me why this could happen?
Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you monitoring memory usage?

Comment: Also, consider to start printing the values you get from the file after X million lines (or just use a debugger) in order to see when exactly the problem occurs.

Comment: Penny to a pound you are running out of memory

Comment: Put your code in a try block and catch `std::bad_alloc&` (include <exception>) If this happens, you have ran out of memory.

Comment: check mapping.max_size() and also do mapping.size()

Comment: You compiling/running 32 or 64-bit?

Comment: @VittorioRomeo I did, and thats how I found outit stops at different lines. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @john If it runs out of memory, it should throw an OutofMemory Error is it? I never get this error.....

Comment: @user1502952 I did that, and it's not because it gets bigger than the max size of map. I even try to put the records into two maps, still cannot.

Comment: @user2733551 You need to *catch* the out of memory error. `try { ... } catch (const std::exception& e) { std::cerr << e.what() << '\n'; }`

Answer (score 0):

It is always advisable `***not to read entire file***` at once in memory as file size could vary from small kbs to bigger Mbs.

It's better to read in chunks say few fixed thousand bytes(say 4092) every time you read from file do your processing and close it.

Comment: `std::map<>` is neither arbitrarily nor specifically limited; the allocatable memory space of the *process*, however, *is*. One Ring To Rule Them All.

Comment: @WhozCraig, yes i agree.

Comment: @user1502952  Mabe that's the case. Thanks. But if I just read the file and do not put into map, it can execute well till the end of file. This happens when I want to insert into the map. And it happens exactly at the mapping[stemp]=itemp line.

Comment: If I close the file, how do I find the place where I finished my last chunk?